# Splitting field of $x^6-6x^4-10x^3+12x^2-60x+17$

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

The one I want to know exactly is the Galois group of minimal polynomial of $a=\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3]5$. If the splitting field $E$ of $m_a$ is the subfield of $Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3]5,\eta)$, where $\eta$ is primitive 3rd root of 1, then by using Galois theory, I show that the size of orbit of a is 6, so $x^6-6x^4-10x^3+12x^2-60x+17$ is irreducible and minimal polynomial of $a$, and hence $m_a$ is irreducible, hence separable. Since $Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3]5)$ is included in $E$, not same, and $[Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3]5):Q]=6$, $E=Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3]5,\eta)$. The problem is the first part: is $E$ the subfield of $Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3]5,\eta)$? I think so, but I can't prove this without direct calculation. Am I wrong, or am I missing some simple facts?

Comment: The splitting field of $m_a$ is $E$, because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{5})$.

Comment: I don't get that implies splitting field of $m_a$ is $E$. Can you explain more?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $a = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}$ is
$$m_a(x) = \prod_{\substack{1 \leq j \leq 2\\ 1 \leq k \leq 3}}(x - ((-1)^j\sqrt{2} + \eta^k\sqrt[3]{5}),$$
where $\eta$ is a primitive cube root of unity. Clearly $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is a subfield of the splitting field of $m_a$. But we also need $\eta$, so $\mathbb{Q}(a, \eta)$ is a subfield of the splitting field. We have
$$\mathbb{Q}(a, \eta) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{5}, \eta) = E,$$
over which $m_a$ clearly splits, so $\mathbb{Q}(a, \eta)$ is the splitting field.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.